# Swift search function

Tags: javascript, swift, search, uiwebview

The following is the JavaScript I have which functions what I am after is "Swift " which will do the same thing.  The search would be working on a HTML file not on a table as almost every search tutorial I have seen does.  I am not asking for this code to be translated, although that would be great, I am after somewhere to find out where I can learn how to write a similar function that will get me the same results.  Any help would be great.

```
<script>
    function FindNext () {
        var str = document.getElementById ("findInput").value;
        if (str == "") {
            alert ("Please enter some text to search!");
            return;
        }

        if (window.find) { 
            var found = window.find (str);
            if (!found) {
                alert ("The following text was not found:\n" + str);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you plan to run swift on a webpage?

Comment: @Bergi The "web page" you refer to is an html file viewed through a uiwebview (all text, over  6000 lines of html) in an app which already works.  What I need is a search function to search in the same way as the Javascript you see above does but in Swift.